# Android Realm plugin is causing ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, realm, classnotfoundexception

Me and my team are developing a simple Android app which is using three external libraries, loaded inside the 'libs' directory, to send commands to a USB Printer.

These libraries are working fine, but when we try to integrate the Realm plugin they stop working.

Do you have any idea why this happens? Please let me know if you need further informations.

#### Steps:

- Adding `classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.5.0"` in the Project **build.gradle**, everything still works as it should
- Adding `apply plugin: 'realm-android'` in the Module **build.gradle**, external libraries stop working

#### Technical info:

```
Android Studio for Mac: 2.3.3
Gradle version: 2.3.3
compileSdkVersion: 25
buildToolsVersion: 25.0.3
minSdkVersion: 19
targetSdkVersion: 25
```

#### Crash log:

```
08-01 16:41:51.797 18080-18080/it.apptoyou.android.taxrefund W/System.err: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.common.sdk.printer.UsbPrinterManager
08-01 16:41:51.797 18080-18080/it.apptoyou.android.taxrefund W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
08-01 16:41:51.798 18080-18080/it.apptoyou.android.taxrefund W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
08-01 16:41:51.798 18080-18080/it.apptoyou.android.taxrefund W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:273)
08-01 16:41:51.798 18080-18080/it.apptoyou.android.taxrefund W/System.err:     at com.telpo.tps550.api.printer.UsbThermalPrinter.start(UsbThermalPrinter.java:126)
08-01 16:41:51.798 18080-18080/it.apptoyou.android.taxrefund W/System.err:     at it.apptoyou.android.taxrefund.controllers.utils.PrinterManager.setupPrinter(PrinterManager.java:59)
08-01 16:41:51.798 18080-18080/it.apptoyou.android.taxrefund W/System.err:     at it.apptoyou.android.taxrefund.App.onCreate(App.java:42)
08-01 16:41:51.798 18080-18080/it.apptoyou.android.taxrefund W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1012)
08-01 16:41:51.799 18080-18080/it.apptoyou.android.taxrefund W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4553)
08-01 16:41:51.799 18080-18080/it.apptoyou.android.taxrefund W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
08-01 16:41:51.799 18080-18080/it.apptoyou.android.taxrefund W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
08-01 16:41:51.799 18080-18080/it.apptoyou.android.taxrefund W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-01 16:41:51.799 18080-18080/it.apptoyou.android.taxrefund W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
08-01 16:41:51.799 18080-18080/it.apptoyou.android.taxrefund W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
08-01 16:41:51.799 18080-18080/it.apptoyou.android.taxrefund W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-01 16:41:51.799 18080-18080/it.apptoyou.android.taxrefund W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-01 16:41:51.799 18080-18080/it.apptoyou.android.taxrefund W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:925)
08-01 16:41:51.799 18080-18080/it.apptoyou.android.taxrefund W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:720)
08-01 16:41:51.799 18080-18080/it.apptoyou.android.taxrefund W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.common.sdk.printer.UsbPrinterManager" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/it.apptoyou.android.taxrefund-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/it.apptoyou.android.taxrefund-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
08-01 16:41:51.800 18080-18080/it.apptoyou.android.taxrefund W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
08-01 16:41:51.800 18080-18080/it.apptoyou.android.taxrefund W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
08-01 16:41:51.800 18080-18080/it.apptoyou.android.taxrefund W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
08-01 16:41:51.800 18080-18080/it.apptoyou.android.taxrefund W/System.err:  ... 17 more
08-01 16:41:51.800 18080-18080/it.apptoyou.android.taxrefund W/System.err:  Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.common.sdk.printer.UsbPrinterManager
08-01 16:41:51.801 18080-18080/it.apptoyou.android.taxrefund W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
08-01 16:41:51.801 18080-18080/it.apptoyou.android.taxrefund W/System.err:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
08-01 16:41:51.801 18080-18080/it.apptoyou.android.taxrefund W/System.err:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
08-01 16:41:51.801 18080-18080/it.apptoyou.android.taxrefund W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
08-01 16:41:51.801 18080-18080/it.apptoyou.android.taxrefund W/System.err:      ... 18 more
08-01 16:41:51.801 18080-18080/it.apptoyou.android.taxrefund W/System.err:  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: do you use multidex?

Comment: @eriuzo We've tried to set `multiDexEnabled` both true and false, with no success.

Comment: `nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/it.apptoyou.android.taxrefund-2/lib/arm` this thing seems to be normal `armeabi` which Realm doesn't ship since 2.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Proguard make sure your `proguard-rules.pro` is configured well.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know anything about Proguard, but we are using the default `proguard-rules.pro` file (empty).

Comment: Ok, practically, not Realm is causing an error by Printing library (https://github.com/mobileprint/android-print-sdk). Please check if you import it correctly

Comment: We are not using the **Android Print SDK** and we can't use it because the app we're developing runs on an dedicated hardware which includes an USB Printer (and its SDK jar libraries). If we remove Realm everything works fine. Could it be an architecture problem? Maybe Realm is forcing the app to run in a specific architecture not supported by the library? If this could be the case, what can we do to prevent or fix this behaviour?

Comment: @DavideBalistreri I think it's the other way around. An option would be to use Realm 1.2.0

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thank you for your feedback! We tried to change the Realm version to 1.2.0 and even previous versions. The issue is still present, although I think it's an architecture problem. Do you have any advice?

Comment: Hm. 1.2.0 had support for armeabi. If that still doesn't fix it, then it's some sort of 32-bit vs 64-bit mismatch.